# Xcode 4.3.2 error message

Tags: xcode

my project blows up with this message:
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I've taken out all of the offending code (i think), and I've even deleted everything back to the original classes, but I still get the messages.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

here's the entire log:

```
Ld /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewTest-gwytsbxrryxjejdbvifxuyomdpug/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NewTest.app/NewTest normal i386
    cd "/Users/xxxx/Desktop/NewTest copy"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewTest-gwytsbxrryxjejdbvifxuyomdpug/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewTest-gwytsbxrryxjejdbvifxuyomdpug/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewTest-gwytsbxrryxjejdbvifxuyomdpug/Build/Intermediates/NewTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NewTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/NewTest.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewTest-gwytsbxrryxjejdbvifxuyomdpug/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NewTest.app/NewTest

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController.testprop3 in /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewTest-gwytsbxrryxjejdbvifxuyomdpug/Build/Intermediates/NewTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NewTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/OtherClass.o and /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewTest-gwytsbxrryxjejdbvifxuyomdpug/Build/Intermediates/NewTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NewTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ViewController.testprop3 in /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewTest-gwytsbxrryxjejdbvifxuyomdpug/Build/Intermediates/NewTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NewTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/OtherClass.o and /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewTest-gwytsbxrryxjejdbvifxuyomdpug/Build/Intermediates/NewTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NewTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o for architecture i386
```

Comment: Can you post the whole log for the error? This usually means that you are missing a library which it cannot find.

Comment: Ok i'll try to post the whole thing, but I'm don't understand how I "lost" a library by adding code???

Comment: It can just as well be a missing dependency.. Just add the log and I'll have a look.

Comment: here's the entire log. thaks.

Comment: The error says duplicate symbols.  Are you somehow linking the same object twice or have multiple source files that implement ViewController?

Comment: Please post the content of `/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewTest-gwytsbxrryxjejdbvifxuyomdpug/Build/Intermediates/NewTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NewTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/NewTest.LinkFileList`

Comment: got it!  I was linking the same object twice.  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have double defined testprop3.